# Retrieving rows with the same length

Tags: r

I have a big data.frame that structurally looks like this:

```
a <- c("hort", 3:8)
b <- c("hort", 2:5,"NA", "NA")
d <- c("hort", 1:3, "NA", "NA", "NA")
z <- c("hort", 4:8, "NA")
y <- c("hort", 1:2, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")
x <- c("hort", 1:4, "NA", "NA")
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(a,b,d,z,y,x))
df <- sapply(df, as.character)
df[df=="NA"] <- ""

    V1     V2   V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
1   hort    3   4   5   6   7   8
2   hort    2   3   4   5        
3   hort    1   2   3            
4   hort    4   5   6   7   8    
5   hort    1   2                
6   hort    1   2   3   4
```

I would like to retrieve in a separate data.frame the rows which have exactly four values when starting counting from the second column. In this case this would be rows 2 and 6. So the output would look like this

```
  V1    V2  V3  V4  V5
1 hort   2  3   4    5
2 hort   1  2   3    4
```

I have found few posts on retrieving rows that satisfy a condition, but neither is reflective of my problem.
So far I thought to use

```
subset(df,length (df[1:6,]==5))
```

But it does not work

> error: 'subset' must be logical)

And I can not get my head around it since it seems a logic expression to me. Also maybe someone can suggest a better solution than sub setting the whole data.frame.

Comment: what happens if you have 4 values in column V2 to V7 but located in different columns? What is the expected output?

Comment: This is a good question. The df I have does not have blank spaces in between columns with values in the same row. So it is not a worry in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df[which(rowSums('' != df) == 5), ]
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `which()`. It should be sufficient to use `df[rowSums(df!="")==5,]`.

Answer (score 2):

`df` is actually a matrix. You can do:

```
df[rowSums(df[,-1]!="")==4,]
#     V1     V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 V7
#[1,] "hort" "2" "3" "4" "5" "" ""
#[2,] "hort" "1" "2" "3" "4" "" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[rowSums(apply(df[,-1], 2, "!=", ""))==4,]
     V1     V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 V7
[1,] "hort" "2" "3" "4" "5" "" ""
[2,] "hort" "1" "2" "3" "4" "" ""
```

I don't understand why you're converting your df to character but assumed that's what you want to do.